# Перенос виджета Wordpress в другую тему

Tags: wordpress

Ситуация такая.
Есть у меня сайт на Wordpress. Там скачаная тема cheerup.
В теме есть стандартный красивый слайдер для постов.
Вот так он выглядит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел где находится этот виджет.
Вот собственно его код.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Widget to show posts in a list format in sidebar
 */
class Bunyad_Posts_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
 /**
  * Setup the widget
  * 
  * @see WP_Widget::__construct()
  */
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct(
   'bunyad-posts-widget',
   esc_html_x('Cheerup - Posts List', 'Admin', 'cheerup'),
   array('description' => esc_html_x('Popular Posts/Latest Posts widget for sidebar.', 'Admin', 'cheerup'), 'classname' => 'widget-posts')
  );
 }
 
 /**
  * Widget output 
  * 
  * @see WP_Widget::widget()
  */
 public function widget($args, $instance)
 {
  extract($args);
  $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
  
  // Setup the query
  $query_args  = array('posts_per_page' => $instance['number'], 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1);
  
  // Popular by comments
  if ($instance['type'] == 'popular') {
   $query_args = array_merge($query_args, array('orderby' => 'comment_count'));
  }
  
  // Most liked
  if ($instance['type'] == 'liked') {
   $query_args = array_merge($query_args, array(
     'meta_key' => '_sphere_user_likes_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
   ));
  }
  
  // Limited by tag?
  if (!empty($instance['limit_tag'])) {
   $query_args = array_merge($query_args, array('tag' => $instance['limit_tag']));
  }
  
  $query = new WP_Query(apply_filters('bunyad_widget_posts_query_args', $query_args));  
  $style = (!empty($instance['style']) ? $instance['style'] : '');
  $image = 'cheerup-thumb';
  
  // Default to showing category - for backward compatibility
  $meta_cat = (!array_key_exists('meta_cat', $instance) ? true : $instance['meta_cat']);
  
  if ($style == 'large') {
   $image = 'cheerup-thumb-alt';
  }
  
  ?>

  <?php echo $args['before_widget']; ?>
  
   <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
    
    <?php
     echo $args['before_title'] . esc_html($title) . $args['after_title']; // before_title/after_title are built-in WordPress sanitized
    ?>
    
   <?php endif; ?>
   
   <ul class="posts<?php echo esc_attr(!empty($style) ? ' ' . $style : ''); ?>">
   <?php  while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="post cf">
    
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="image-link">
      <?php 
       the_post_thumbnail( 
        $image, 
        array('title' => strip_tags(get_the_title())
       )); 
      ?>
     </a>
     
     <div class="content">
      
      <?php if (empty($style)): ?>
       <?php Bunyad::core()->partial('partials/post-meta', array('show_title' => false, 'show_cat' => $meta_cat)); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
     
     
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-title<?php echo (!empty($instance['trim_title']) ? ' limit-line' : ''); 
       ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      
       
      <?php if ($style == 'meta-below' OR $style == 'large'): ?>
       <?php Bunyad::core()->partial('partials/post-meta', array('show_title' => false, 'show_cat' => $meta_cat)); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      
       
      <?php if (!empty($instance['excerpt'])): // show excerpt? ?>
      
       <div class="excerpt"><?php echo Bunyad::posts()->excerpt(null, 15, array('add_more' => false)); ?></div>
      
      <?php endif;?>
      
     </div>
    
    </li>
   <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
   </ul>
  
  <?php echo $args['after_widget']; ?>
  
  <?php
 }
 
 /**
  * Save widget
  * 
  * Strip out all HTML using wp_kses
  * 
  * @see wp_filter_post_kses()
  */
 public function update($new, $old)
 {
  foreach ($new as $key => $val) {
   $new[$key] = wp_kses_post($val);
  }
  
  $new['excerpt'] = !empty($new['excerpt']) ? 1 : 0;
  $new['meta_cat'] = !empty($new['meta_cat']) ? 1 : 0;
  
  return $new;
 }
 
 /**
  * The widget form
  */
 public function form($instance)
 {
  $defaults = array('title' => '', 'type' => '', 'number' => 4, 'style' => '', 'excerpt' => 1, 'trim_title' => 0, 'meta_cat' => 1, 'limit_tag' => '');
  $instance = array_merge($defaults, (array) $instance);
  extract($instance);
  
  ?>
  
  <p>
   <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Title:', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
   <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>" name="<?php 
    echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('title')); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
  </p>
  
  <p>
   <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('type')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Sorting:', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
   
   <select id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('type')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('type')); ?>" class="widefat">
    <option value="" <?php selected($type, ''); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Latest Posts', 'Admin', 'cheerup') ?></option>
    <option value="popular" <?php selected($type, 'popular'); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Most Commented', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
    <option value="liked" <?php selected($type, 'liked'); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Most Liked', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
   </select>
  </p>
  
  <p>
   <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('number')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Number of posts to show:', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
   <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('number')); ?>" name="<?php 
    echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('number')); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($number); ?>" size="3" />
  </p>
  
  <p>
   <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('style')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Style:', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
   
   <select id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('style')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('style')); ?>" class="widefat">
    <option value="" <?php selected($style, ''); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Default - Meta Above', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
    <option value="meta-below" <?php selected($style, 'meta-below'); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Default - Meta Below', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
    <option value="large" <?php selected($style, 'large'); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Alternate - Larger Image & Meta', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
   </select>
   
  </p>
  
  
  <p>
   <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('limit_tag')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('From this Tag (Optional):', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
   
   <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('limit_tag')); ?>" name="<?php 
    echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('limit_tag')); ?>" type="text" class="widefat" value="<?php echo esc_attr($limit_tag); ?>" />
  </p>
 
  <p>
   <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('excerpt')); ?>" name="<?php 
    echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('excerpt')); ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php checked($excerpt); ?> />
    
   <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('excerpt')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Show Excerpt', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
  </p>
  
  <p>
   <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('meta_cat')); ?>" name="<?php 
    echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('meta_cat')); ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php checked($meta_cat); ?> />
    
   <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('meta_cat')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Show Category', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
  </p>
  
  <p>
   <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('trim_title')); ?>" name="<?php 
    echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('trim_title')); ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked($trim_title); ?> />
    
   <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('trim_title')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Limit Title to One Line', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
  </p>
 
  <?php
 }
}
```

введите сюда код

Первая странность для меня - это отсутствие хука для инициализации виджета.
Мне кажется должен быть еще какой то код типо.

```html
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
     register_widget( 'bunyad-posts-widget' );
});
```

Впрочем хука нет но виджет работает.
Я взял и пенерес файл php в новую тему на другой сайт. 
Назвал я файл
widget-posts.php
Подключил в functions

```html
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );
include('partials/widgets/widget-posts.php');
```

Не работает
В итоге переписал код и зарегестрировал как новый виджет.
Вот что получилось

```html
<?php
class widget_carousel_thumb extends WP_Widget {
     public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct(
                 'widget_carousel_thumb',
                 'Карусель Виджет',
                 array( 'description' => __( 'Виджет для вывода карусели', 'text_domain' ), )
           );
     }

  /**
   * Widget output 
   * 
   * @see WP_Widget::widget()
   */
  public function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args);
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
    
    // Setup the query
    $query_args  = array('posts_per_page' => $instance['number'], 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1);
    
    // Popular by comments
    if ($instance['type'] == 'popular') {
      $query_args = array_merge($query_args, array('orderby' => 'comment_count'));
    }
    
    // Most liked
    if ($instance['type'] == 'liked') {
      $query_args = array_merge($query_args, array(
        'meta_key' => '_sphere_user_likes_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
      ));
    }
    
    // Limited by tag?
    if (!empty($instance['limit_tag'])) {
      $query_args = array_merge($query_args, array('tag' => $instance['limit_tag']));
    }
    
    $query = new WP_Query(apply_filters('bunyad_widget_posts_query_args', $query_args));    
    $style = (!empty($instance['style']) ? $instance['style'] : '');
    $image = 'cheerup-thumb';
    
    // Default to showing category - for backward compatibility
    $meta_cat = (!array_key_exists('meta_cat', $instance) ? true : $instance['meta_cat']);
    
    if ($style == 'large') {
      $image = 'cheerup-thumb-alt';
    }
    
    ?>

    <?php echo $args['before_widget']; ?>
    
      <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
        
        <?php
          echo $args['before_title'] . esc_html($title) . $args['after_title']; // before_title/after_title are built-in WordPress sanitized
        ?>
        
      <?php endif; ?>
      
      <ul class="posts<?php echo esc_attr(!empty($style) ? ' ' . $style : ''); ?>">
      <?php  while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="post cf">
        
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="image-link">
            <?php 
              the_post_thumbnail( 
                $image, 
                array('title' => strip_tags(get_the_title())
              )); 
            ?>
          </a>
          
          <div class="content">
            
            <?php if (empty($style)): ?>
              <?php Bunyad::core()->partial('partials/post-meta-alt-afterpost', array('show_title' => false, 'show_cat' => $meta_cat)); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
          
          
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-title<?php echo (!empty($instance['trim_title']) ? ' limit-line' : ''); 
              ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            
              
            <?php if ($style == 'meta-below' OR $style == 'large'): ?>
              <?php Bunyad::core()->partial('partials/post-meta-alt-afterpost', array('show_title' => false, 'show_cat' => $meta_cat)); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            
              
            <?php if (!empty($instance['excerpt'])): // show excerpt? ?>
            
              <div class="excerpt"><?php echo Bunyad::posts()->excerpt(null, 15, array('add_more' => false)); ?></div>
            
            <?php endif;?>
            
          </div>
        
        </li>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </ul>
    
    <?php echo $args['after_widget']; ?>
    
    <?php
  }
  
  /**
   * Save widget
   * 
   * Strip out all HTML using wp_kses
   * 
   * @see wp_filter_post_kses()
   */
  public function update($new, $old)
  {
    foreach ($new as $key => $val) {
      $new[$key] = wp_kses_post($val);
    }
    
    $new['excerpt'] = !empty($new['excerpt']) ? 1 : 0;
    $new['meta_cat'] = !empty($new['meta_cat']) ? 1 : 0;
    
    return $new;
  }
  
  /**
   * The widget form
   */
  public function form($instance)
  {
    $defaults = array('title' => '', 'type' => '', 'number' => 4, 'style' => '', 'excerpt' => 1, 'trim_title' => 0, 'meta_cat' => 1, 'limit_tag' => '');
    $instance = array_merge($defaults, (array) $instance);
    extract($instance);
    
    ?>
    
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Title:', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
      <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title')); ?>" name="<?php 
        echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('title')); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
    </p>
    
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('type')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Sorting:', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
      
      <select id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('type')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('type')); ?>" class="widefat">
        <option value="" <?php selected($type, ''); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Latest Posts', 'Admin', 'cheerup') ?></option>
        <option value="popular" <?php selected($type, 'popular'); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Most Commented', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
        <option value="liked" <?php selected($type, 'liked'); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Most Liked', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
      </select>
    </p>
    
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('number')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Number of posts to show:', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
      <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('number')); ?>" name="<?php 
        echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('number')); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($number); ?>" size="3" />
    </p>
    
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('style')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Style:', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
      
      <select id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('style')); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('style')); ?>" class="widefat">
        <option value="" <?php selected($style, ''); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Default - Meta Above', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
        <option value="meta-below" <?php selected($style, 'meta-below'); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Default - Meta Below', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
        <option value="large" <?php selected($style, 'large'); ?>><?php echo esc_html_x('Alternate - Larger Image & Meta', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></option>
      </select>
      
    </p>
    
    
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('limit_tag')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('From this Tag (Optional):', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
      
      <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('limit_tag')); ?>" name="<?php 
        echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('limit_tag')); ?>" type="text" class="widefat" value="<?php echo esc_attr($limit_tag); ?>" />
    </p>
  
    <p>
      <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('excerpt')); ?>" name="<?php 
        echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('excerpt')); ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php checked($excerpt); ?> />
        
      <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('excerpt')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Show Excerpt', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
      <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('meta_cat')); ?>" name="<?php 
        echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('meta_cat')); ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php checked($meta_cat); ?> />
        
      <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('meta_cat')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Show Category', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
      <input id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('trim_title')); ?>" name="<?php 
        echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('trim_title')); ?>" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked($trim_title); ?> />
        
      <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('trim_title')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html_x('Limit Title to One Line', 'Admin', 'cheerup'); ?></label>
    </p>
  
    <?php
  }
}


add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
     register_widget( 'widget_carousel_thumb' );
});
```

Подключил его как
include('partials/widgets/widget-carousel-thumb.php');

Виджет появился в админке в поле виджетов НО.
после активации получаю везде адские глюки.
Помогите разобраться а?

-Теперь стал смотреть где же находится класс Bunyad, зашел в functions.php и увидел там везде встречается это слово. 
Насколько я понял это фреймворк который подключен в тему Wordpress.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста где можно почитать чтобы понять как это работает.
У меня начало кода вот такое.

```html
<?php
// Already initialized?
if (class_exists('Bunyad_Core')) {
 return;
}

// Initialize Framework
require_once get_template_directory() . '/lib/init.php';

// Fire up the theme - make available in Bunyad::get('cheerup')
Bunyad::register('guardian-child', array(
 'class' => 'Bunyad_Theme_Cheerup',
 'init' => true
));

/**
 * Main Framework Configuration
 */

$bunyad_core = Bunyad::core()->init(apply_filters('bunyad_init_config', array(

 'theme_name'    => 'guardian-child',
 'meta_prefix'   => '_bunyad',    // Keep meta framework prefix for data interoperability 
 'theme_version' => '2.2.0',

 // widgets enabled
 'widgets'      => array('about', 'posts', 'cta', 'ads', 'social', 'subscribe'),
 'widgets_type' => 'embed',
 'post_formats' => array('gallery', 'image', 'video', 'audio'),
 'customizer'   => true,
 
 // Enabled metaboxes and prefs - id is prefixed with _bunyad_ in init() method of lib/admin/meta-boxes.php
 'meta_boxes' => array(
  array('id' => 'post-options', 'title' => esc_html_x('Post Options', 'Admin: Meta', 'guardian-child'), 'priority' => 'high', 'page' => array('post')),
  array('id' => 'page-options', 'title' => esc_html_x('Page Options', 'Admin: Meta', 'guardian-child'), 'priority' => 'high', 'page' => array('page')),
 )
)));
```

В итоге при моих попытках интеграции в тему сайт отдает ошибку 500.
Что если я захочу собрать тему одну из нескольких. Из одной слайдер, из второй виджет инстаграма, из третей стили и тд.......
Помогите пожалуйста ссылкой на документацию или подсказкой. Я то не пойму что делать.

Comment: Ну начнем с того, что код виджета вы перенесли, а его стили, и, класс, который использует старая тема ? Где у вас описан к примеру класс `Bunyad` и элементы , методы, который он использует ?

Comment: Пока не знаю. Спасибо за наводку. Пробегусь по всем классам сегодня и буду писать как удается.

Comment: Впринцыпе, Вам достаточно пробежатся по методам класса, и шаблнам, так как внутри с вероятностью 100% все написано с помощью функций ядра WP.

Comment: Я так понимаю я все классы могу найти в style.css или в других файлах стилей (если есть) и переместить в свои стили. А дальше шаблоны понаходить и скопировать в одну папку, а потом поменять путь к этим файлам

Comment: стили да, классы я имел ввиду ООП.

Comment: Я нашел эту штуку но не могу понять как это работает. Снизу дописал..... помогите если можно.

Comment: сейчас Вам надо просто переписать метод нужного класа на свою функцию темы или виджета, в самом класе вы можете увидетиь логику раюоты вывода и труктуру, но вот перенести все с зависимостями врятли будет просто.

Comment: Ладно. Вчера начал читать с нуля про фреймворки и разработку своих тем для  Wordpress. Надеюсь что удастся разобраться со всем и сделать так себе как нужно.

Comment: если не углубляться и с пояснениями рекомендую почитать статьи на wp-kama.ru и описание хуков с ядра WP.

Comment: Спасибо большое.